# Angular2 Lazy loading not displaying data but loading htmlpage in Network

Tags: angular2-routing, angular4-router

Angular2 LazyLoading When i click on Link its Loading Its component,Htmlpages,Modules But not display Html page in `<router-outlet>`

**Masterpage**

```
<a [routerLink]="['Customer/Add']">Customer</a><br />
<a [routerLink]="['Employee/Add']">Employee</a><br />
    <router-outlet>
    </router-outlet>
```

**CustomerComponent**

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core"    
@Component({
     templateUrl: '../../ui/customer/customer.html'
})
export class CustomerComponent {

}
```

**CustomerModule**

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(CustomerRoute), ReactiveFormsModule, CommonModule, ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule, HttpModule],
    declarations: [CustomerComponent],
    bootstrap: [CustomerComponent]
}) 
export class CustomerModule {    
}
```

**CustomerRoute**

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core"
import { CustomerComponent } from "../components/customer/customercomponent"

export const CustomerRoute = [
    { path: "Add", Component: CustomerComponent}
    ]
```

**MainRoute**

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core"
import { Routes } from "@angular/router"
import { HomePageComponent } from "../components/homepage/homepage"
export const ApplicationRoutes= [
    { path: '', component: HomePageComponent },
    { path: 'UI/MasterAngularPage.html' ,component: HomePageComponent },
    { path: 'Customer', loadChildren: '../modules/customermodule/customermodule#CustomerModule'},

]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use following code to redirect on add route.

```
export const CustomerRoute = [
    { path: "", redirectTo: "Add", pathMatch:"full"},
    { path: "Add", Component: CustomerComponent}
]
```

Remove bootstrap code from CustomerModule.

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(CustomerRoute), ReactiveFormsModule, CommonModule, ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule, HttpModule],
    declarations: [CustomerComponent]
})
```

Hope it will help